# What is the (current) fate of the model(s) of the Reliant used in the filming of Star Trek II?

Tags: star-trek, props

Subject pretty much says it all...does anybody know what happened to it? One presumes that there was more than one.

Comment: I guess either auctioned or struck. But that's just my guess.

Comment: Perhaps more on-topic for [movies.se], but I'd vote to close as too (time) localized.

Comment: [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/what-happened-to-the-original-models-from-star-trek) is on-topic, so I think this one is as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least two of the models were sold during the fan auction a few years back, including a [normal one](http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/lot/uss-reliant-model-4780548-details.aspx?from=salesummary&intObjectID=4780548&sid=5d02e8b4-cd0b-4566-a6ef-6d9978368275) and a [battle damaged](http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/lot/small-battle-damaged-uss-reliant-minature-model-4780547-details.aspx?from=salesummary&intObjectID=4780547&sid=5d02e8b4-cd0b-4566-a6ef-6d9978368275) version.

[image]

Comment: $60K?! Someone must *really* want it badly.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this model has basically been ALL of the Miranda-class ships for which a model was needed since the class was unveiled in Star Trek II. So, it was originally Reliant, then its name and number were changed to become the NCC-1887 USS Saratoga seen in Star Trek IV, and then the number changed (but the name kept, possibly for time reasons) to become the NCC-31911 Saratoga for the DS9 pilot/spinoff episode Emissary. After the pilot, the DS9 series used digital models for all ships including MANY Miranda-class vessels.

Answer (score 0):

It's been redressed as the Saratoga I and II as well as Captain Batesman's Soyuz class starship. In the latter case, you can see a lot of additions to distinguish it from the Miranda class.

I think in the Star Trek universe, the Miranda Class of the 23rd and early 24th century was Starfleet's version of the mass produced "all purpose" light cruiser. Cheaper than a Constitution or Enterprise class heavy cruiser and more capable than the destroyer. In most games, it's an intermediate between the destroyer (or sometimes Oberth "Grissom" class) and the Constitution/Enterprise classes. Slower but more powerful than the former and faster and almost equally armed as the Constitution/Enterprise but not as much power generated and can't take as much punishment in battle.